# Flask Mail ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: email, flask

I am following this basic tutorial from the link exactly:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_mail.htm

Anyone know what cause this problem? I think it should be a common problem?

Is there any additional setting for flask mail?

Here is the full error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/Users/boxia/PycharmProjects/learn_flask/test.py", line 18, in index
        mail.send(msg)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
        with self.connect() as connection:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
        self.host = self.configure_host()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 156, in configure_host
        host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1029, in __init__
        source_address)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
        self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
        server_hostname=self._host)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
        _context=self, _session=session)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
        self.do_handshake()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Comment: Are you getting the error on install? Please add a code snippet showing how you got the error.

Comment: it turn out to be the network issue, my workplace don't allow to use port 25 or 465